# when you use paperclip in rails what are the permissions in the created folders?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, linux, paperclip

when you use paperclip in rails under Linux, what are the permissions of the paperclip created folders?

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Paperclip is used when you want to attach a file into model. I'm not sure about the permissions, but they should permit writing by user under which rails app is running and reading for HTTP server. Probaly 0755

Comment: i have big permissions problem with my paperclip, i'd like someone with an actual paperclip install to answer.